# Need mysql query to find manager name

Tags: mysql

yesterday i got a database knowledge test for junior programmer. and the question is like this :

given Table 1.0

[image]

write a query to make a result like this :

[image]

please anybody help me how to write a query for this question. thanks in advance

Comment: So we should help you cheat the test?

Comment: no, i got this test yesterday. i just wanna know the answer for my evaluation.

Comment: and make sure i wrote a right answer. :)

Comment: What was your answer?

Comment: i didnt answer it. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` the table with itself:

```
select e.employeeID,
    e.employeeName,
    m.employeeName as managerName
from your_table e
left join your_table m on e.managerID = m.employeeID;
```